# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier never returns

Tags: xcode, uitableview, parsing

When I call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` it is freezing my code and does never return any cell (or `nil`) I change the code from my custom class to a `UITableViewCell` to be sure the problem wasn't in my class, I also create a brand new empty cell to call with the identifier.

I add a log before and after the call for `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` as you can see in the screenshot the one before gets called once and the one after never.

[image]

I try to clean and build, clean the project folder, delete DerivedData, restart the computer. I can't see any exceptions or what is really holding the code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might not change anything to your problem, but I'm not sure you're using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` right. It should be returning an Optional cell but you're force-casting it to an explicitly unwrapped cell (the `as! UITableViewCell` part). Try removing the cast and adding and `if (cell == nil) { ... }` check after that to instantiate a new cell if the dequeue operation returned `nil` (which is impossible with your current code).

Comment: I try that too it also does not return nil

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If you already registered the cell identifier `"cellOverview"` somewhere in your storyboard, you could try using the newer method, which guarantees returning a cell (non-Optional). Try this if you're using storyboards: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOverview", forIndexPath: indexPath)`

Comment: I think that it has nothing to do with dequeuing the cell. something else is freezing your thread.

Comment: In my case the this queation solved the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611789/uitextview-with-text-less-than-10-characters-hangs-ios-9

Comment: In my case the this question solved the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611789/uitextview-with-text-less-than-10-characters-hangs-ios-9

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened to XCode, but, if someone find the same problem here is what I had to do.

I didn't find anything wrong with the cell (yes I was using storyboard and the identifier was set correctly) and noting was wrong with the code in the custom class as well. I even went to the point of create a secondary custom class and custom cell and it did not help, so I try to put a invalid identifier and even there XCode did not return me an error (as it should).

I had to delete my custom cell from the storyboard, as soon as I did that all start to work again, first the error that the identifier didn't exist, than the temporary one start to work, than I recreate the original one (exactly as before) and all start to work again.

Very overkill but worked for me. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I'm having the same kinda problem. All is set fine. Even 10 more prototype cells are loading fine, only one is doing the problem. I checked identifier text for typos etc. Tried cleaning project too. But nothing happens.. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is expressed that you are printing `println("return dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier")`, but can't see your `return cell` code at the end of your function, that must conform to your function expectation.

Comment: well it is bellow and you cannot see in the screenshot, however  there is two points here, first and more important the code wouldn't compile if I wasn't return a cell as it is required for the function, second we need to agree that: to get to the return statement the line of code println("return dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier") MUST be executed first.

Comment: Try like this: `let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellOverview") as UITableViewCell!`. By the way, what Xcode are you using? I found some difference unwrapping optionals depending on the Xcode version.