# iOS 9 pushViewController not working, in iOS 8 everything works as expected, zero code changes?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7

When I use `pushViewController`, `viewWillDisappear` (first view controller) is called. After that, the screen freezes, hence no action is performed and I put breakpoint on `nextviewcontroller`, it doesn't get called in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
//first View Controller from where pushViewController
 [[AppCommonFunctions sharedInstance]pushVCOfClass:[NextViewController class] fromNC:[self navigationController] animated:YES popFirstToVCOfClass:nil modifyVC: ^(id info) {
            [((NextViewController *)info)setEventInfo : object];
        }];


//common method for push view controller in another file
- (void)pushVCOfClass:(Class)class1 fromNC:(UINavigationController *)nc animated:(BOOL)animated popFirstToVCOfClass:(Class)class2 modifyVC:(operationACFFinishedBlock)modify {
RESIGN_KEYBOARD
[self popToViewControllerOfKind : class2 from : nc];
UIViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[class1 description]];
if (modify) {
    modify(vc);
    modify = nil;
}
[nc pushViewController:vc animated:animated];
 }
        - (UIViewController *)popToViewControllerOfKind:(Class)aClass from:(UINavigationController *)navController {
RESIGN_KEYBOARD
if (aClass) {
    NSArray *arrayOfViewControllersInStack = navController.viewControllers;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfViewControllersInStack.count; i++) {
        if ([[arrayOfViewControllersInStack objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:aClass]) {
            int index = (i > 0) ? (i - 1) : i;
            [navController popToViewController:[arrayOfViewControllersInStack objectAtIndex:index] animated:NO];
            break;
        }
    }
    return [navController topViewController];
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: well is vc non-nil when you push it -- add assert(vc) and assert(nc) too

Comment: where i can add assert? can u explain please @Daij-Djan

Comment: `assert(vs != nil)` right before you push it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your NextViewController have any UITextView you must have to give its **default textValue** in storyboard and changes its value from code by doing this it works fine for me you can also try.(i don't reason behind that but its working for me)

Comment: change its(UITextView) default value for text in storyboard

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this problem too. I found the CPU usage is 100% after `pushViewController:animated:`, and the runloop is stuck. The view controller fails to load the view in `loadView`.

The `loadView` process might be changed internally in iOS 9, or the storyboard/xib file is misconstructed due to Xcode 7 (maybe just a bug).

#### Step 1, try to load view before push

I've tried to print the `view` property to enforce the view controller calling `loadView`.

```
UIViewController *vc = ...;
NSLog(@"vc.view: %@", vc.view);  // Never print
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I found the view can't be load when calling `view` property. The `NSLog()` will not print the view object, and the runloop is stuck.

#### Step 2, reveal the call stack when loading view

Adding the following `loadView` implementation in the target view controller.

```
- (void)loadView
{
  NSLog(@"will loadView");
  [super loadView];
  NSLog(@"did loadView");
}
```

Build and run your app, and try to trigger the `loadView` by calling the property `view`. Now you should find the app is stuck at `[super loadView]` in the target view controller.

Now try to pause the execution (Debug » Pause, or `cmd + ctrl + Y`) several times, and you should found that the app (runloop) is almost stuck at some specific methods. In my instance, my app is stuck at `-[NSLocalizableString length]` (or `objc_msgSend`).

I think this is a hint for debugging (My view controller is constructed by storyboard and the storyboard is localized in the project directly).

---

## Update

After I reset the storyboard file back to previous version by version control (git), the app works well and the view is loaded successfully.

Comment: I had the exact same behavior and I had to recreate my entire viewcontroller in my storyboard and re-attach everything to my class

Comment: following above step it stuck on objc_msgSend ....  what i do to solve this problem? @BrettDiDonato

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of iOS 9.0. UITextView should have minimum 10 characters by default. However you can change it later in viewDidLoad method.
Reference : [UITextView with text less than 10 characters hangs iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611789/uitextview-with-text-less-than-10-characters-hangs-ios-9)