# UITextView cause CPU to go 100%

Tags: ios, uitextview, cpu-usage

As soon as "self.navigationController pushviewcontroller:vc animated:YES" is executed, my CPU goes to 100%. I searched for the same issue on Stack Overflow and found that `UITextView` might be creating such problem. I removed `UITextView` and it started working fine.
What is it to do with UITextView? What can I do to use it?

I have IB of UITextView

```
@property(nonatomic ,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *txtvwMessage;
```

Also I have UITextView's delegate Outlet to my View controller class.

Comment: Have you tried pausing the app and seeing what it's doing (hint: look at the call stack)?

Comment: Found the solution. It is a bug of iOS 9.0. UITextView should have minimum 10 characters by default. I entered more characters in storyboard UItextView -> Property -> text. Started working like charm.

Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611789/uitextview-with-text-less-than-10-characters-hangs-ios-9

Answer (score 0):

My advise to you is to profile your application using `Instruments` to see what method is using the majority of CPU time. You can then trace back on method stack trace to come to a conclusion. You can use `Time Profiler`. It would be hard to tell otherwise with such small information!

Answer (score -1):

Try not to retain the text view. Use the assign/weak as follows:-

```
@property(nonatomic ,assign) IBOutlet UITextView *txtvwMessage;
```

OR

```
@property(nonatomic ,weak) IBOutlet UITextView *txtvwMessage;
```

Now check the CPU percentage usage.

Comment: How does that cause high CPU usage?

Comment: I found the correct answer. UITextView should have minimum 10 characters by default (bug of iOS 9.0)
Reference : stackoverflow.com/questions/32611789/

Comment: Yeah the OP said the same thing 4 hours ago.  You should delete your incorrect answer.

Comment: I think other people must learn from my mistake and it prevent to publish wrong answers to the same question. I agree that my answer was incorrect, but if I delete it then other person may make the same faulty thing to this question. So let it be. If it still sounds weird, then I will delete it.