# UITableView Cell Shows Blank after upgrading into Xcode 7 iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

Am fetching data from server, and am able to receive all the data, but it shows  blank cell when I run the project. When I keep the breakpoint I understood that the code is not executing after the  `VisitorsTableViewCell *cell = (VisitorsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`.

**NOTE:** this code worked perfectly in xcode 6.4

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    // Number of sections is the number of regions
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section

    return [VisitorsNameArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VisitorsTableCell";

    VisitorsTableViewCell *cell = (VisitorsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.visitorName.text = [VisitorsNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.visitorComment.text =  [VisitorsCommentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.visitorDate.text =  [VisitorsDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.visitorLocation.text =  [VisitorsLocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it ,i dont know what wrong with the XCode 7.

I deleted my custom  table cell from Storyboard and start all work again,and recreate with same design.Now it works perfectly.

Comment: recreating the cell didn't solve it for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it?,i just deleted and add new cell ,thats how it works for me,anyway plz check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899426/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-never-returns